# How to add divider's in android's TabLayout's style? TabLayout is new from the design support library

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout in my app, and I want to insert a divider between tabs because the default look of a TabLayout has no divider in it. How can I do this?

Comment: you mean between tabs?

Comment: put borders on items.. form the divider you want...

Comment: yes, between the tabs @Fasiha check this out https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#design-support-library TabLayout is from the new design support library

Comment: did you find solution to add divider?

Comment: not yet @MiteshSharma

Comment: I am also searching forthe same. The TabLayout supposed to have all previous answers. Now, it does not even support divider, which is a basic need.

Comment: Answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204184/how-to-set-the-divider-between-tabs-in-tablayout-of-design-support-library