# Is there a way to add vertical line between each tab in TabLayout

Tags: android

The TabLayout is quite userful building a sliding tab for viewpager, except there is no way you can add vertical line between tabs just like TabHost in code or xml as far as I know, so is there other way to do so with ease?

Comment: You can try below link for solving your problem.

Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204184/how-to-set-the-divider-between-tabs-in-tablayout-of-design-support-library?lq=1

Answer (score 55, accepted):

TabLayout is actually a horizontal scrollable LinearLayout.

Just use following code to add dividers:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    linearLayout.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    drawable.setSize(1, 1);
    linearLayout.setDividerPadding(10);
    linearLayout.setDividerDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: nice solution, better than adding custom views. Thanks!

Comment: better than adding custom views  Thank you

Comment: This solution works for me, but its also add a divider before the first item even i set show_divider_middle.

Comment: Awesome! Simple solution.

Comment: This isn't true for the newer TabLayout in material package. See: `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` which is a `HorizontalScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

You can add manually line in your tab_indicator layout file.

for Horizontal line,

```
<View
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/line"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:background="your color" />
```

and for Vertical line

```
<View
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:id="@+id/line"
     android:layout_width="1dp"
      android:background="your color" />
```