# Tabview with background images in android

Tags: android

sorry for my bad English ,I am create Tabs similar to whats app but how to place image background in  between tab and app name when i select any tab separate image image can be visible please help me any one  sample image below i need like this any one tell me please
[image]

Comment: post what you have tried till now

Comment: i am create tab view its working fine it just like whats app but i want like above image ,how to convert my tab like above images@koutuk

Comment: Use Custom SlideTabLayout with View pager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the divider between Tabs in TabLayout of design support library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204184/how-to-set-the-divider-between-tabs-in-tablayout-of-design-support-library)

Comment: i using two classes for getting tab views SliddeTabLayout and SlideTabStrip@piyush Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Try this

set your image in AppBarLayout background.

and replace your content layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.lcom53.toolbarapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:background="@drawable/photo"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add    `android:background="#00000000"` or `android:background="@drawable/img_transparent"` in your appbar like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```