# How to change gravity of indicator of widget TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator, android-tablayout

Here I'm trying to change the position of `TabIndicator` to top from bottom but not getting success. I want just like as image is showing.
I have done everything but indicator is in bottom not in top and even I can't add dividers between Tabs too. Please look at my code and help me to solve this issue.

My code is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <com.cws.widget.MyTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:tabBackground="@color/drawer_tab_background"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/green"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />


<com.cws.widget.NonSiwpablePager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And styles.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

MyTabLayout.java

```
public class MyTabLayout extends TabLayout {
public MyTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;
    }
    heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}
}
```

ViewPager.java

```
public class NonSiwpablePager extends ViewPager {
public NonSiwpablePager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonSiwpablePager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: are you using custom tablayout??

Comment: Obviously. But I'm confused about it

Comment: please update that class also. or you can use different image and change on selecting deselecting

Comment: Please check again. And this is one of selectors for image and title http://pastie.org/private/5lsxm7l8qoay4naobuddow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to remove that tab indicator,

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
```

this line add into `<com.cws.widget.MyTabLayout>` `xml` file. and after that add that http://pastie.org/private/5lsxm7l8qoay4naobuddow as background

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab"
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: `tabBackground` changed the complete background of Tab

Comment: yes it will change the complete background .so you can change image according to that

Comment: I'm already doing that. You mean I'll have to ask for complete images now.

Comment: image is the better option otherwise how will you manage the text and icon color... if u can manage that then go with color option

Comment: yea, I know I'm doing this for text and icon too. Now I asked for new images and it worked.

Comment: Do you know about divider too between these tabs?

Comment: i think divider attribute is not there so you have to do it custom

Comment: 212121.....and by using tabBackground I lost my background color what I was using.

Comment: I'll get by using new images and false case

Comment: abhi dekhne toh de pehle bahut kaam hai layout hi itna bada hai

Comment: wo divider ka bata de...maine custom layout se liya toh dur bhaag gaye sab k sab

Comment: @AnshulTyagi tu jo image mang rha h usko with border mang qki custom se try kiya mne but wo nhi ho rhi h

Comment: or use this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204184/how-to-set-the-divider-between-tabs-in-tablayout-of-design-support-library

Comment: arey aisa hi kiya maine wo indicator k theek niche nahi rehta

Comment: with border me ro rha hai wo.

Comment: indicator k niche kya nhi rhta??

Comment: divider line...dur rehti hai bahut

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98571/discussion-between-android-and-anshul-tyagi).